# How to write an ipython alias which executes in python instead of shell?

Tags: python, macros, ipython, alias, ipython-magic

We can define an [alias](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/magics.html#magic-alias) in ipython with the `%alias` magic function, like this:

```
>>> d
NameError: name 'd' is not defined
>>> %alias d date
>>> d
Fri May 15 00:12:20 AEST 2015
```

This escapes to the shell command `date` when you type `d` into ipython.

But I want to define an alias to execute some *python* code, in the current interpreter scope, rather than a shell command.  Is that possible?  How can we make this kind of alias?

I work in the interactive interpreter a lot, and this could save me a lot of commands I find myself repeating often, and also prevent some common typos.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The normal way to do this would be to simply write a python function, with a `def`.  But if you want to alias a [statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#simple-statements), rather than a function call, then it's actually a bit tricky.

You can achieve this by writing a custom [magic](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tutorial.html#magic-functions) function.  Here is an example, which effectively aliases the `import` statement to `get`, within the REPL.

from IPython.core.magic import register_line_magic

```
@register_line_magic
def get(line):
    code = f"import {line}"
    print("-->", code)
    exec(code, globals())

del get  # in interactive mode-remove from scope so function doesn't shadow magic
```

*edit: below is the previous code, for older versions of IPython*

```
from IPython.core.magic_arguments import argument, magic_arguments

@magic_arguments()
@argument('module')
def magic_import(self, arg):
    code = 'import {}'.format(arg)
    print('--> {}'.format(code))
    self.shell.run_code(code)

ip = get_ipython()
ip.define_magic('get', magic_import)
```

Now it is possible to execute `get` statements which are aliased to `import` statements.

**Demo:**

```
In [1]: get json
--> import json

In [2]: json.loads
Out[2]: <function json.loads>

In [3]: get potato
--> import potato
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<string> in <module>()

ImportError: No module named potato

In [4]:
```

Of course, this is extendible to arbitrary python code, and [optional arguments are supported aswell](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/api/generated/IPython.core.magic_arguments.html#module-IPython.core.magic_arguments).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know since when IPython provides macro, but now you can simply do this:

```
ipy = get_ipython()
ipy.define_macro('d', 'date')
```

You can put this code into any file located in `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/`, and then this macro will be automatically available when you start IPython.

However, a macro doesn't accept arguments. So pleaes keep this in mind before you choose to define a macro.